# Why does exec(escapeshellcmd("rm -rf /var/www/temp/storage/$userId/")) remove the parent directory when the php file runs in the background?

Tags: php

I have the following two php scripts

**remove_directory.php**

```
<?php
start_session();
$userId = $_SESSION['userId'];
exec(escapeshellcmd("rm -rf /var/www/temp/storage/$userId/"));
?>
```

**indirectly_remove_directory.php**

```
<?php
start_session();
exec("nohup php remove_directory.php > /var/www/temp/log.txt &"); 
?>
```

When I run `remove_directory.php` from the cgi, it works as expected, recursively removing `/var/www/temp/storage/$userId/` but when I run `indirectly_remove_directory.php` from the cgi, it does not work as expected since it recursively removes `/var/www/temp/storage/`.

Why does the entire storage directory get removed when I run `indirectly_remove_directory.php`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because when it's in the background, it's a command line PHP script, which will NOT have the session cookie available that the in-webserver version does. As such, you get a brand new CLEAN session, meaning that your exec call is actually:

```
rm -rf /var/www/temp/storage//
```

because $userID is blank/null.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and clear explanation.  Is there an alternative method to run `remove_directory.php` in the background without it hanging up the user's browser?

Comment: You could just pass $userID from the parent script to the child script as a command line argument. PHP supports the usual C-style `argc` array for arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Just making a guess here, but are you sure that the userid is set when run indirectly? Just upvoted the below answer as it is what I meant, but was added as I was adding my answer